# C - accessing index in array of chars gives strange results including lot of other elements

Tags: c

So given this:

```
int main ()
{

  char names[23][5] = {
    "BkCan",
    "BkChg",
    "BkDel",
    "BkExc",
    "BkPrg",
    "BkRep",
    "Halt",
    "Order",
    "Price",
    "Trade",
    "UpdPr",
    "lBkCa",
    "lBkCh",
    "lBkDe",
    "lBkEx",
    "lBkPr",
    "lBkRe",
    "lHalt",
    "Orde1",
    "lPric",
    "lTrad",
    "lUpdP",
    "lOrde",
};

  printf("%s\n", names[4]);

  return 0;
}
```

I get the result `BkPrgBkRepHalt`

which is a concatenation of multiple elements (5,6,7)

what is going on?

Here's a usable online repl/example:

https://repl.it/repls/UnrealisticDefiantPoodle

Comment: better change that to `char names[23][6]`

Comment: Like yano said, 5 is too short. 6 chars are needed for null termination. "Halt" with null termination can actually fit. That's why it stops printing at that point.

Comment: *"This question was caused by a simple typographical error."*  Voting to close.

Comment: @abelenky What is the typo? It seems OP intentionally wrote this code but failed to understand what it meant

Comment: Another possible solution is `printf("%.5s\n", names[4]);`

Comment: @M.M thanks. Yes, I failed to account for the null terminating character in the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to allocate at least 6 characters for each string, as they each need the null-terminator `\0` (`"BkCan"` is effectively `"BkCan\0"`).

At the moment, `printf` is continuing to read from the pointer you give it until it reaches a null-terminator (after a 4-character string like `"Halt"`, for example, or one past the end of the array (undefined behaviour)), hence the "concatenation" effect.

Just doing:

```
char names[23][6] = ...
```

should be enough.